# SonarQube OKTA SAML authentication

Tags: sonarqube, okta

I have installed Sonarqube from helm chart sonarqube/sonarqube, when adding  authentication via Okta as a SAML identity provider according to the documentation  https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/10.2/instance-administration/authentication/saml/overview/, I get following error "You're not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator.
Reason: The response was received at
http://.../oauth2/callback/saml instead of https://.../oauth2/callback/saml"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUzh6.png)

Sonarqube version is 10.2